# Mongo DB aggregation optimization (Spring Data)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, optimization, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot (2.4.2) in my application and MongoDB as the database. I have 1.1M documents in a single collection and I am trying to do some aggregations, my document structure looks like this:

[image]

In java code my aggregation query looks like this:

```
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            
            match(where("gameRef")
                    .is(gameRef)),

            group("platformRef", "gameRef", "currency")
                    .sum("bet")
                    .as("bet")
                    .sum("win")
                    .as("win")
                    .sum("data.bonusWin")
                    .as("bonus")
                    .count()
                    .as("count"),

            project("platformRef", "gameRef", "currency")
                    .andInclude("bet")
                    .andInclude("win")
                    .andInclude("bonus")
                    .andInclude("count")
    );

    AggregationResults<SpinReport> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, SpinHistory.class, SpinReport.class);
    return results.getMappedResults();
```

This gives me this aggregation in MongoDB language:

```
{
  "aggregate": "__collection__",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$match": {
        "gameRef": "6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54"
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "platformRef": "$platformRef",
          "gameRef": "$gameRef",
          "currency": "$currency"
        },
        "bet": {
          "$sum": "$bet"
        },
        "win": {
          "$sum": "$win"
        },
        "bonus": {
          "$sum": "$data.bonusWin"
        },
        "count": {
          "$sum": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "platformRef": "$_id.platformRef",
        "gameRef": "$_id.gameRef",
        "currency": "$_id.currency",
        "bet": 1,
        "win": 1,
        "bonus": 1,
        "count": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This query takes 5 seconds to execute (in 1.1M documents). I wonder if there is any way to optimize it?
I created these indexes in that collection:

[image]

and I can see that gameRef field index is being used when I execute this query, but it doesn't make any difference in terms of performance. It still takes 5 seconds.

Is it possible to somehow make this work faster?

EDIT:

by running explain plan for this query:

```
db.spinHistory.explain().aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "gameRef": "6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "platformRef": 1,
      "gameRef": 1,
      "currency": 1,
      "win": 1,
      "bet": 1,
      "bonusWin": "$data.bonusWin",
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "platformRef": "$platformRef",
        "gameRef": "$gameRef",
        "currency": "$currency"
      },
      "bet": {
        "$sum": "$bet"
      },
      "win": {
        "$sum": "$win"
      },
      "bonus": {
        "$sum": "$data.bonusWin"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "platformRef": "$_id.platformRef",
      "gameRef": "$_id.gameRef",
      "currency": "$_id.currency",
      "bet": 1,
      "win": 1,
      "bonus": 1,
      "count": 1
    }
  }
])
```

suggested by @Yahya, I can see this:

```
{
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "queryPlanner": {
          "plannerVersion": 1,
          "namespace": "oak9e_rgs_temp.spinHistory",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {
            "gameRef": {
              "$eq": "6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54"
            }
          },
          "queryHash": "27C08187",
          "planCacheKey": "E204EC8C",
          "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
            "transformBy": {
              "bet": true,
              "platformRef": true,
              "win": true,
              "currency": true,
              "gameRef": true,
              "bonusWin": "$data.bonusWin",
              "_id": false
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern": {
                "gameRef": 1,
                "platformRef": 1,
                "currency": 1,
                "bet": 1,
                "win": 1,
                "data.bonusWin": 1
              },
              "indexName": "idx_spin_history_main_fields",
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "multiKeyPaths": {
                "gameRef": [],
                "platformRef": [],
                "currency": [],
                "bet": [],
                "win": [],
                "data.bonusWin": []
              },
              "isUnique": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "gameRef": [
                  "[\"6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54\", \"6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54\"]"
                ],
                "platformRef": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "currency": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "bet": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "win": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "data.bonusWin": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "platformRef": "$platformRef",
          "gameRef": "$gameRef",
          "currency": "$currency"
        },
        "bet": {
          "$sum": "$bet"
        },
        "win": {
          "$sum": "$win"
        },
        "bonus": {
          "$sum": "$data.bonusWin"
        },
        "count": {
          "$sum": {
            "$const": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": true,
        "bet": true,
        "bonus": true,
        "count": true,
        "win": true,
        "platformRef": "$_id.platformRef",
        "gameRef": "$_id.gameRef",
        "currency": "$_id.currency"
      }
    }
  ],
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "DESKTOP-V3NTFPM",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "4.4.3",
    "gitVersion": "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

And this is the index I create for all fields that are being used in this query:

```
{
  "v": 2,
  "key": {
    "gameRef": 1,
    "platformRef": 1,
    "currency": 1,
    "bet": 1,
    "win": 1,
    "data.bonusWin": 1
  },
  "name": "idx_spin_history_main_fields",
  "background": false
}
```

With execution stats:

```
{
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "queryPlanner": {
          "plannerVersion": 1,
          "namespace": "oak9e_rgs_temp.spinHistory",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {
            "gameRef": {
              "$eq": "6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54"
            }
          },
          "queryHash": "27C08187",
          "planCacheKey": "E204EC8C",
          "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
            "transformBy": {
              "gameRef": true,
              "win": true,
              "platformRef": true,
              "bet": true,
              "currency": true,
              "bonusWin": "$data.bonusWin",
              "_id": false
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern": {
                "gameRef": 1,
                "platformRef": 1,
                "currency": 1,
                "bet": 1,
                "win": 1,
                "data.bonusWin": 1
              },
              "indexName": "idx_spin_history_main_fields",
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "multiKeyPaths": {
                "gameRef": [],
                "platformRef": [],
                "currency": [],
                "bet": [],
                "win": [],
                "data.bonusWin": []
              },
              "isUnique": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "gameRef": [
                  "[\"6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54\", \"6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54\"]"
                ],
                "platformRef": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "currency": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "bet": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "win": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "data.bonusWin": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        },
        "executionStats": {
          "executionSuccess": true,
          "nReturned": 1145023,
          "executionTimeMillis": 4473,
          "totalKeysExamined": 1145023,
          "totalDocsExamined": 0,
          "executionStages": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
            "nReturned": 1145023,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 623,
            "works": 1145024,
            "advanced": 1145023,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 1295,
            "restoreState": 1295,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "transformBy": {
              "gameRef": true,
              "win": true,
              "platformRef": true,
              "bet": true,
              "currency": true,
              "bonusWin": "$data.bonusWin",
              "_id": false
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "nReturned": 1145023,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 161,
              "works": 1145024,
              "advanced": 1145023,
              "needTime": 0,
              "needYield": 0,
              "saveState": 1295,
              "restoreState": 1295,
              "isEOF": 1,
              "keyPattern": {
                "gameRef": 1,
                "platformRef": 1,
                "currency": 1,
                "bet": 1,
                "win": 1,
                "data.bonusWin": 1
              },
              "indexName": "idx_spin_history_main_fields",
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "multiKeyPaths": {
                "gameRef": [],
                "platformRef": [],
                "currency": [],
                "bet": [],
                "win": [],
                "data.bonusWin": []
              },
              "isUnique": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "gameRef": [
                  "[\"6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54\", \"6047a10c58ed573e490b8f54\"]"
                ],
                "platformRef": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "currency": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "bet": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "win": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "data.bonusWin": [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
              },
              "keysExamined": 1145023,
              "seeks": 1,
              "dupsTested": 0,
              "dupsDropped": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "nReturned": NumberLong(1145023),
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberLong(4074)
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "platformRef": "$platformRef",
          "gameRef": "$gameRef",
          "currency": "$currency"
        },
        "bet": {
          "$sum": "$bet"
        },
        "win": {
          "$sum": "$win"
        },
        "bonus": {
          "$sum": "$data.bonusWin"
        },
        "count": {
          "$sum": {
            "$const": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "nReturned": NumberLong(3),
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberLong(4467)
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": true,
        "bonus": true,
        "count": true,
        "win": true,
        "bet": true,
        "platformRef": "$_id.platformRef",
        "gameRef": "$_id.gameRef",
        "currency": "$_id.currency"
      },
      "nReturned": NumberLong(3),
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberLong(4467)
    }
  ],
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "DESKTOP-V3NTFPM",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "4.4.3",
    "gitVersion": "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of an index isn't an issue (which sounds like it doesn't). Then remove all of these new indexes that you have created for your aggregation pipeline. Create the following index:

```
{ gameRef: 1, platformRef: 1, currency: 1, bet: 1, win: 1, "data.bonusWin": 1 }
```

Which is essentially indexing all the fields you need.

All you need next is projection.

So, between `match` and `group` stage. Add another stage for projection like:

```
{ _id: 0, gameRef: 1, platformRef: 1, currency: 1, bet: 1, win: 1, "data.bonusWin": 1 }
```

Important bit here is to project out `_id`

After edits are made  to the question, it is evident that's the best it can get. But it is still 4seconds long.

Possible solutions:

1. Don't run the aggregation pipeline every time. Use a $merge stage to create materialised view. And query it from there.
2. Create a summary collection, this can be done from the app code itself, or can be done using Change Streams (those again work in app scope).

Comment: I have created an index and added a projection like you mentioned, but it doesn't make any difference unfortunately. Query response time is ~5s. Doesn't matter where I execute it, via java code or via mongo compass, execution time is the same.

Comment: Did you run explain plan?

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis can you run explain plan like `.explain("executionStats")`

Comment: Added "With execution stats:" section in my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Looking at the executionStats, this is the most efficient you can get. You will need to resolve it with schema.

Comment: What do you mean with schema? Can you add more info please?